# Middle center elements are getting out of screen, without scroll possibility

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

**Hi there!**
I'm trying to center elements to middle of the screen and they are getting out of it, without scroll possibility.

**Some screenshots with problem:**
[image: Mobile problem view]

[image: Desktop problem view]

**A part of CSS code**:

```
...
.user-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
...
```

**A part of HTML code:**

```
...
<div class="user-content">
    <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2">
        <!-- Profile Card -->
        <div class="profile-card text-center m-auto">
        ...
        </div>

        <!-- Profile Details -->
        <div class="profile-details text-white m-auto mt-3 lg:mt-0">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Attach full code

Comment: It's too much code, I can't.

Comment: i think it's better if you can provide us a link to a version of it

Comment: add it here https://jsfiddle.net/ and send link.

Comment: https://codepen.io/wYonut/pen/WNJaayB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change styles for `body` and `.user-content`. Like that.

```
body {
  background: #23272A;
  font-family: "Inter";
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.user-content {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500&display=swap");
body {
  background: #23272A;
  font-family: "Inter";
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:100vh;
}

.home-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.home-content .header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.home-content .header p {
  font-size: 14.5px;
}
.home-content .user_lookup input {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
  background: #2C2F33;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;
}
.home-content .user_lookup input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.home-content .user_lookup input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .home-content .user_lookup input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.home-content .user_lookup button {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
  background: #525EE7;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;
}
.home-content .user_lookup button:hover {
  background: #4754e2;
}
.home-content .user_lookup button:disabled {
  background: rgb(116, 126, 245);
}
.home-content .error {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  color: #eb3434;
}
.home-content .more-features {
  background: #2C2F33;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;
}
.home-content .more-features p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.home-content .more-features a[href^="https:"] {
  color: rgb(112, 124, 255);
}
.user-content {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.user-content .profile-card {
  background: #1f2325;
  width: 15rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px -1px;
}
.user-content .profile-avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.user-content .profile-name {
  color: #D3D3D3;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.user-content .profile-tag {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
.user-content .profile-status {
  background: #1D2022;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.user-content .profile-status p {
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  font-size: 13.5px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.user-content .profile-online {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  margin-left: 9rem;
  background: #3ba55d;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.user-content .profile-do-not-disturb {
  background: #df4446;
}
.user-content .profile-idle {
  background: #faa81a;
}
.user-content .profile-offline {
  background: #757f8c;
}
.user-content .profile-badges img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.user-content .profile-badges img + img {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.user-content .profile-details {
  background: #1f2325;
  max-width: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px -1px;
}
.user-content .profile-details h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.user-content .profile-details p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify, .user-content .profile-games {
  background: #1f2325;
  max-width: 30rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px -1px;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify-header {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background: #21d363;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify-tumbnail, .user-content .profile-game-tumbnail {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify-details, .user-content .profile-game-details {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
.user-content .profile-game + .profile-game {
  border-top: 1px solid #1D2022;
}

footer p {
  color: #9e9e9e;
  font-size: 12px;
}
footer a {
  color: rgb(112, 124, 255);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 672px) {
  .user_lookup button {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  footer p {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Discord Press - Yonut#4185</title>

    <!-- TailwindCSS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  
    <style>
        body {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Auto refresh -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; URL=user?id=469151928904056842">
<style>/* ! tailwindcss v3.1.8 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:#e5e7eb}::after,::before{--tw-content:''}html{line-height:1.5;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;font-family:ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"}body{margin:0;line-height:inherit}hr{height:0;color:inherit;border-top-width:1px}abbr:where([title]){-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}table{text-indent:0;border-color:inherit;border-collapse:collapse}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-weight:inherit;line-height:inherit;color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit],button{-webkit-appearance:button;background-color:transparent;background-image:none}:-moz-focusring{outline:auto}:-moz-ui-invalid{box-shadow:none}progress{vertical-align:baseline}::-webkit-inner-spin-button,::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}summary{display:list-item}blockquote,dd,dl,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,pre{margin:0}fieldset{margin:0;padding:0}legend{padding:0}menu,ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}input::placeholder,textarea::placeholder{opacity:1;color:#9ca3af}[role=button],button{cursor:pointer}:disabled{cursor:default}audio,canvas,embed,iframe,img,object,svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}img,video{max-width:100%;height:auto}*, ::before, ::after{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::-webkit-backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }.absolute{position:absolute}.m-auto{margin:auto}.mt-2{margin-top:0.5rem}.mb-2{margin-bottom:0.5rem}.mt-3{margin-top:0.75rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.mb-5{margin-bottom:1.25rem}.mt-5{margin-top:1.25rem}.inline-block{display:inline-block}.inline{display:inline}.grid{display:grid}.rounded-full{border-radius:9999px}.text-center{text-align:center}.align-middle{vertical-align:middle}.font-medium{font-weight:500}.text-white{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}@media (min-width: 640px){.sm\:grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))}}@media (min-width: 1024px){.lg\:mt-0{margin-top:0px}.lg\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))}}</style></head>
<body>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="user-content">
        <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2">
            <!-- Profile Card -->
            <div class="profile-card text-center m-auto">
                <center>
                    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/469151928904056842/3efd650df9ac59aad457f7e59f3be965.webp" alt="Profile Avatar Image" class="profile-avatar rounded-full" id="profile-avatar" draggable="false">
                                            <div class="profile-online rounded-full absolute "></div>
                                    </center>
                <h1 class="profile-name mt-2">Yonut</h1>
                <h4 class="profile-tag mb-2">#4185</h4>
                <center>
                    <div class="profile-badges mt-3"><img src="img/badges/House_Bravery.svg" class="inline" draggable="false" title="House Bravery"></div>
                </center>
                                <div class="profile-status mt-4">
                    <p>
                        https://yonutdev.xyz                    </p>
                </div>
                            </div>
            <!-- End of Profile Card -->
            
            <!-- Profile Details -->
            <div class="profile-details text-white m-auto mt-3 lg:mt-0">
                <!-- Creation Date -->
                <h4>CREATION DATE</h4>
                <p id="creation-date" class="mb-5 mt-3">July 18th, 2018</p>

                <!-- Account Age -->
                <h4>ACCOUNT AGE</h4>
                <p id="age" class="mt-3 mb-5">1543 days, 9 hours </p>

                <!-- Developer ID -->
                <h4>DEVELOPER ID</h4>
                <p id="developer-id" class="mt-3">469151928904056842</p>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Profile Details -->
        </div>

        
        <!-- Game Activity -->
                <div class="profile-games mt-5 mb-5 m-auto">
            <div class="profile-game">
                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-assets/383226320970055681/565945770067623946.png" class="profile-game-tumbnail m-auto" draggable="false">
                <div class="align-middle text-center">
                    <h3 class="profile-game-title text-white font-medium inline-block">Visual Studio Code</h3>
                    <p class="profile-game-details text-white">
                        Editing styles.scss<br>Workspace: htdocs                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <!-- End of Game Activity -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Content -->
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any "overflow: hidden;" statements in your code? If so, try removing them, if you don't, try changing the position from "position: absolute;" to "position: relative". Absolute places the object relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Comment: I don't have any overflow statements in my CSS code and If I try to set position relative, it's not going very well, page content is no longer centered in the middle of the screen.

Comment: That's probably because the  "position: absolute;" statement positions objects relative to their ancestors, meaning that they were going to be aligned either way, however this can also cause objects to go off-screen, and not include a scroll option., try going back to "position: relative;", and add some tags to center the objects